# Need help in exact output of Batch Programming

Tags: batch-file

I am running the code:

```
netsh wlan show profile name=%INPUT% key=clear | findstr Key>password.txt
```

output (in password.txt text file):

```
Key Content            : mywifipassword
```

I need output only "mywifipassword" in separate file password.txt.

Don't want "Key Content :" word in my output file.

Answer (score 1):

to catch the output of a command into a variable, use a `for` loop:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('netsh wlan show profile name^="%input%" key^=clear ^|find  "Key Content"') do set "pwd=%%a"
>password.txt echo(%pwd:~1%
```

The `for` gets the second token (after the colon), so you need to remove the space at the beginning.

Comment: it shows output as **~1** bro. No use. I donno mistake is mine or code. i just copy and pasted the code u have sent with bat extension and input as my wifi name it shows output file **~1**

Comment: only, when there is no `Key Content` (then `pwd` is empty). Avoid with `if defined pwd echo %pwd:~1%`

Comment: Password is not empty. when running `netsh wlan show profile name=%INPUT% key=clear | findstr Key>password.txt` it shows password. But running above code showing error output (~1 or blank)

Comment: sorry, there was a problem copying the code. Edited. Please try again.

Comment: huhoo.. :D Hi #stephan Finnally worked by added `/p` next to `do set` . Thanks a lot for the clue and help bro. So Kind of you :) Really happieeee a lot. Final working code = `for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('netsh wlan show profile name^="%input%" key^=clear ^|find  "Key Content"') do set /p "pwd=%%a"
>password.txt`

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a in ('netsh wlan show profile name=%INPUT% key=clear ^| findstr Key') do set "password=%%b"
echo %password:~1%>password.txt
```

The command is placed within quotes and the pipe `|` escaped with a caret `^` to indicate that the pipe is part of the command, not the `for`.

`for /f` reads each line of output from the command, tokenising on `:`, assigning the first token (up to the `:` into `%%a` and the remainder of the line (after the `:` into `%%b`.

...As Lotpings points out, `%%b` will have a leading space, so put it in a variable and output it from the second character on (1, counting from "character 0")

OR

```
for /f "tokens=3delims=: " %%a in ('netsh wlan show profile name=%INPUT% key=clear ^| findstr Key') do echo %%a>password.txt
```

where the delimiters are `:` or <kbd>Space</kbd>, so token 1 becomes `Key`, token 2 `Content` and token 3 the password.

If the password can contain a space, then use "tokens=2*delims=: " and `echo %%b`

Comment: Magoo, the password will have a leading space. Using `"tokens=2*delims=: "` could fix that

Comment: Hi That too not worked brother. Please help. its not showing exact **mywifipassword** as output. It shows blank or ~1 as output for ur suggested code. Please help

Comment: There are two lines of code. It will show that if you try it all on one line. Can't test for the moment - no wifi.

Comment: Tried in one line also bro no use. :( am struggling a lot. Please help.

Comment: Needs to be two lines. If you execute it as one line, it will show the `...~1...` that you report. The first line sets `password`, the second delivers the password to the file. Please say what exactly is in the variable `password` when you've executed the command. Also, it's a batch file - expected to be executed as a batch file. If you're clicking the batch, then add lines `echo %password%` and `pause` to the end of the file to show the results. It's also very sensitive to layout changes. Cut-and-paste is best. Don'y add extra spaces (like before the `=` in the `set` command`

Comment: @Stephan Read again, I did  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this out,

```
set /p INPUT="Type your wifi name:"
netsh wlan show profile name=%INPUT% key=clear>pass.txt
for /f "tokens=2 delims=[" %%f in (pass.txt) do (for /f "delims=]" %%g in ("%%f") do echo %%g)>password.txt
del pass.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem you encounter is missing UAC. Netsh will not return the Key value unless you start from an elevated cmd window.

The following batch will use PowerShell to run an elevated console with another instance of itself if not already running elevated.

It will recurse all profiles and show profile, SSID and Key.
I do not have windows clients in my Wlan so I can't test it myself.

```
:: Enum-SSIDKEY.cmd
@echo off & setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
:: elevate if not already Admin
net file 1>nul 2>&1 || (powershell -ex unrestricted -Command ^
  "Start-Process -Verb RunAs -FilePath '%comspec%' -ArgumentList '/c %~f0 %*'"
  goto :eof)
:: Put code here that needs elevation
For /F "tokens=3* delims=: " %%A in (
  'netsh wlan show profiles ^|findstr User.Profile '
) Do (Set "SSID=" & Set "Key="
      For /F "tokens=1,2* delims= " %%S in (
        'netsh wlan show profile name^="%%~B" key^=clear ^|findstr "SSID Key"'
      ) Do Set %%S=%%U
      Echo Profile: %%B SSID: %SSID% has Key: %Key%
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try for this code that i have tested it only on my Windows 7 (French Machine) :

```bat
@echo off
:Main
Title  WiFi Password Recovery by Hackoo 2017
Mode con cols=45 lines=30 & color 9E
echo [SSID] Menu :
set "pwd="
echo(
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "skip=2 delims=: tokens=2" %%a in ('netsh wlan show profiles') do (
    if not "%%a"=="" (
        set "ssid=%%a"
        set "ssid=!ssid:~1!"
        echo [!ssid!]
    )
)
EndLocal
echo(
Set /p "Input=Type your SSID Name : "
cls
Mode con cols=85 lines=5
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('netsh wlan show profile name^="%Input%" key^=clear ^|find /I "Conten"') do set "pwd=%%a"
    If defined pwd (
        echo(
        echo  The password of the SSID [%Input%] is ==^> "%pwd:~1%" without double quotes
    ) else (
        echo(
        color 0C
        echo The password of the SSID [%Input%] is empty or not defined !
    )
)
echo(
echo Hit any key to return to SSID Menu
Pause>nul & goto Main
```

Or if you want to save all the passwords in a text file like this :

```bat
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
Title  WiFi Password Recovery by Hackoo 2017
Mode con cols=75 lines=30
cls & color 9E & echo.
ECHO                  **************************************
echo                         WiFi Password Recovery
ECHO                  **************************************
echo.
if _%1_==_Main_  goto :Main

:getadmin
    echo                    %~nx0: elevating self
    set vbs=%temp%\getadmin.vbs
(
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^)
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "Main %~sdp0 %*", "", "runas", 1
)> "%vbs%"
    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
goto :eof
::*************************************************************************************
:Main
echo                        [SSID] ====^> "Password"
echo [SSID] ====^> "Password" > "%~dp0PassWifi.txt"
for /f "skip=2 delims=: tokens=2" %%a in ('netsh wlan show profiles') do (
    if not "%%a"=="" (
        set "ssid=%%a"
        set "ssid=!ssid:~1!"
        call :getpass "!ssid!"
    )
)
echo.
echo.
echo Done
If Exist "%~dp0PassWifi.txt" start "" "%~dp0PassWifi.txt"
pause>nul
exit /b
::*************************************************************************************
:getpass
set name=%1
set name=!name:"=!
Set passwd=
for /f "delims=: tokens=1,2" %%a in ('netsh wlan show profiles %1 key^=clear ^|find /I "Conten"') do (
    set "passwd=%%b"
)
If defined passwd (
    set passwd=!passwd:~1!
    echo                  [!name!] ====^> "!passwd!"
    echo [!name!] ====^> "!passwd!" >> "%~dp0PassWifi.txt"
) else (
    echo                  [!name!] ====^> empty or not defined
    echo [!name!] ====^> empty or not defined >> "%~dp0PassWifi.txt"
)
exit /b
::*************************************************************************************
```